# How to remove parent array in php

Tags: php

I'd like to remove the parent numeric array below group_id and have the recipients array be after group_id.

```
 [1] => Array
    (
        [group_id] => 1234
        [0] => Array
            (
                [recipients] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [recipient_id] => 2
                                [name] => Another Tester
                                [email] => testertest@test.com
                                [phone] => 1230001234
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [recipient_id] => 10
                                [name] => teadsf
                                [email] => newguy@test.com
                                [phone] => 1230001234
                            )
```

Comment: Can there be more numeric indexes other than `[0]` besides `group_id` ?

Comment: No, only one recipients array for each group_id.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to `for..each` loop with some array modification operations:

```
//$input is your original input array

// final output array
$output = array();

// Loop over the array
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

    $output[$key]['group_id'] = $value['group_id'];

    // Set recipients key at the same level as group_id
    // Access the value at [0]['recipients']
    $output[$key]['recipients'] = $value[0]['recipients'];
}
```